# Onde encontro projetos de aplicativos feitos em phonegap prontos para edição?

Tags: android, ios, apache-cordova, aplicação-web

Onde posso encontrar projetos de aplicativos para IOS e/ou Android completamente prontos? Que possa customizar, edita-los e se possível já com comunicação com servidor web, sem que precise fazer um do zero.

Comment: Tente procurar no https://github.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando quiser aplicações prontas recomendo [procurar por *open source*](https://www.google.com.br/search?espv=2&q=phonegap+apps+source+code&oq=phonegap+apps+source).

No site [mobilegap.net](http://www.mobilegap.net/#open-source-cross-platform-applications-built-with-html5), que é o primeiro resultado da consulta no google, já tem 6 aplicações em PhoneGap que tem o código disponibilizado no GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

Bom, se voce usar o intel XDK voce irá ter alguns modelos de app para os dois dentro da IDE! Da para continuar apartir dos modelos!